# How to manage error_log and access_log of apache?

Tags: linux, logs, apache-httpd

I noticed my `error_log` file grows larger and larger.

I tried changing the LogLevel in `httpd.conf` from

```
LogLevel debug
```

to

```
LogLevel emerg
```

But I still see errors being posted about `favicon.ico` not being found and so on.

If I delete `error_log`, I would have to restart `apache`, which causes some downtime for current viewers.

- Is there a way to tell `apache` **NOT** to write any `error_log`?
- OR is there a way to ensure it does not grow beyond 1 mb ( when it is not
  turned off )?

I notice `access_logs` are being "archived",  but I rather want them also not to be created at all.

Do these archived `access_logs` ever get deleted or do I have to delete them myself?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `logrotate`, which allows you to rotate the logs (based on the date, the size...) and to choose how many files you want to keep. For instance, here's my config file for apache:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
        endscript
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a utility such as [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/) to manage the web server log files. Using cronolog, log files can be automatically rotated without having to shut down and restart the web server.

*excerpt*

> cronolog is a simple filter program that reads log file entries from standard input and writes each entry to the output file specified by a filename template and the current date and time. When the expanded filename changes, the current file is closed and a new one opened. cronolog is intended to be used in conjunction with a Web server, such as Apache, to split the access log into daily or monthly logs.